# Как правильно считать время

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть статический класс (мой) в котором я в начале игры достаю из сервера время, как мне потом к нему прибавлять время пройденное в игре что бы каждый раз не доставать из сервера? Каждую секунду ждать IEnumerator не вариант, т.к. не точно идет расчет, сравнивать с текущем на телефона, и уже при надобности прибавлять разницу тоже не вариант, т.к. можно будет просто перевести, есть идея как-то задествовать класс Time, но там же тоже все будет не нормально прибавлять, разве что можно после считания времени возвращать время + Time.time, пойдет ли такой вариант или есть лучше?

Comment: "есть идея как-то задествовать класс Time, но там же тоже все **будет не нормально прибавлять**" - это вам кто такое сказал?

Comment: Риот прав: и на сервере и локально время считается правильно. Независимо одно от второго. Ты сам себе придумал какие-то проблемы и сам пытаешся боротся с ветряными мельницами

Comment: @RiotBr3aker если скрыть игру Time.time же не будет считаться.

Comment: @Andrew я собирался раз за игру взять с сервера, а потом каждый раз кодом считать.

Comment: А в чем проблема посмотреть текущее системное время и отталкиватся от него? Раз уж ты хочешь что бы время шло и в свернутой игре

Comment: @Andrew так вот смена прокрутка времени мешает.

Comment: я тебя не понимаю

Comment: Ну если у вас механики в игре базируются на времени в игре, то что мешает  каждый раз после сворачивания приложения спрашивать время с сервера? А уже после вручную сделать таймер с Time.deltaTime?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я об этом и спрашивал, ведь тогда прийдеться держать переменную которая будет отнимать лишнее время Time.time верно? Можно ли будет тогда проверить открыл игру (после того как скрыл) подключен ли он к интернету?

Comment: Невозможно сделать таймер, который будет считать время в бэкграунде без системных часов (которые вам не подходят) или без сервера. Сервер нужен для получения времени во время запуска приложения и фокуса на него. Time.time не будет работать в данном случае в принципе, вам нужен **Time.deltaTime**. Подключение к интернету вы можете проверить когда вам угодно, вы же программист.